# UITableView in UIView in UIScrollView. When scrolling tableview don't scroll scrollview too

Tags: uitableview, uiview, ios6, uiscrollview

I have a UITableView inside a UIView inside a UIScrollView.
Problem: when i scroll/drag the tableview, the scrollview scrolls too.
What i need is for the tableview not to pass the scroll to the scrollview. Also i need to be able to use the scrollview when i scroll it directly. 
How can i do this? 
Cheers

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it using "hitTest" on the tableview.

```
 - (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

If the event originated within the tableview, i disable the parent's scrollview scroll.
And, when the tableview's scroll has ended (scrollViewDidEndDragging) i re-enable the parent's scrollview scroll.

This seams to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Set a delegate to your tableview's scrollview (i.e your view controller)

```
tableView.scrollView.delegate = self;
```

then use those two calls

```
– scrollViewDidScroll:
– scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate:
```

to disable and re-enable your outside scrollview's scrollEnabled property

Comment: It does not work. For some reason the parent scrollview is called first, before the tableview's scrollViewDidScroll is called.

Comment: What is your scrollview for? Is the tableview always at the bottom of the scrollview?

Comment: Yes, it's always at the bottom, fixed height and width. I fixed the thing by using hittest on the tableview. Thanks for the help.